# Using koa-views with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, koa, koa2

I was trying to use koa-views as my renderer, but I kept getting the message from TS:

```
Property 'render' does not exist on type 'ParameterizedContext<any, IRouterParamContext<any, {}>>'.ts(2339)
```

My app.js

```
import Koa from "Koa";
import views from "koa-views";
import indexRouter from "./routes/index"

const app = new Koa();

app.use(views(`${__dirname}/views`, { autoRender: true, extension: "swig" }));
app.use(indexRouter.routes());
```

index.js - IndexRouter:

```
import Router from "koa-router";
const router = new Router();

router.get("/", async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.render(); // not done yet tho
  await next();
})

export = router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because argument **ctx** type doesn't have method **render()**, but in types lib @types/koa-views declared module (see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/koa-views/index.d.ts#L55).

And you can make this:

```
import { Context, DefaultState } from "koa";
import * as Router from "koa-router";

const router = new Router<DefaultState, Context>();

router.get("/", async (ctx: Context, next) => {
    await ctx.render("/path/");
    await next();
});
```